# Permissões de Módulos

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho esta clase mas na hora de comparar se existe essa permissão dentro do retorno da array, aparece que não tem nenhuma.

A permissão consta na listagem dentro da array.

```
class Permission{

    var $Permission = array();
    var $table = 'permissoes';//Nome tabela onde ficam armazenadas as permissões
    var $pk = 'idPermissao';// Nome da chave primaria da tabela
    var $select = 'permissoes';// Campo onde fica o array de permissoes.

    public function  __construct() {
        log_message('debug', "Permission Class Initialized");
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();

    }

    public function checkPermission($idPermissao = null,$atividade = null){

        echo $idPermissao;


        if($idPermissao == null || $atividade == null){
            return false;
        }
        // Se as permissões não estiverem carregadas, requisita o carregamento
        if($this->Permission == null){
            // Se não carregar retorna falso
            if(!$this->loadPermission($idPermissao)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(is_array($this->Permission[0])){


            //echo $atividade."<br><br>";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->Permission[0]);
            echo "</pre>";
            //die();

            if(array_key_exists($atividade, $this->Permission[0])){
                // compara a atividade requisitada com a permissão.
                if ($this->Permission[0][$atividade] == 1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    private function loadPermission($id = null){

        if($id != null){
            $this->CI->db->select($this->table.'.'.$this->select);
            $this->CI->db->where($this->pk,$id);
            $this->CI->db->limit(1);
            $array = $this->CI->db->get($this->table)->row_array();

            if(count($array) > 0){

                $array = unserialize($array[$this->select]);
                //Atribui as permissoes ao atributo permission
                $this->Permission = array($array);
                return true;


            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

## A listagem do print_r ficou da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aCedentes
    [1] => eCedentes
    [2] => dCedentes
    [3] => vCedentes
    [4] => aUsuarios
    [5] => eUsuarios
    [6] => dUsuarios
)
```

Neste caso, teria que ter sido `TRUE` e não `FALSE`.

Comment: Aqui if(array_key_exists($atividade, $this->Permission[0])){ não encontra $atividade postada... Por mais que tenha na listagem do Permission

Comment: @rray consegue me dar uma força?